# How to filter on the same column twice after groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm having troubles in solving the following problem:

I have a pandas DataFrame similar to:

```
col1 col2 col3

A    P    S
A    C    W
A    C    W
A    C    M

B    P    S
B    C    M
B    C    M

D    P    W
D    C    M
D    C    S
```

and I need to answer the following:

In the same group (from `col1`), how many `C` (in `col2`) are `W` (from `col3`) and have `P` (in `col2`) that are `S` (from `col3`)?
Afterwards, I need to sum up all the counts done for each group altogether.

Writing more schematically, how many `C-W` pairs are in the same `col1` group in which there is a `P-S` pair?
Then, sum all the counts together.

Up to now, I tried to solve this, as follows:

```
pd_h = pd_h\
    .groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3"])\
    .filter(
        lambda x: ((x["col2"].iloc[0] == 'C') & (x["col3"].iloc[0] == "W")
            if ((x["col2"].iloc[0] == 'P') & (x["col3"].iloc[0] == "S")) else False)
    ).describe(["count"])  # here describe, because I may decide to put also "mean", "std", etc.
```

But the remaining pairs `C-W` may belong to a group in which there is not a pair `P-S`.

How may I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3
0    A    P    S
1    A    C    W
2    A    C    W
3    A    C    M
4    B    P    S
5    B    C    M
6    B    C    M
7    D    P    W
8    D    C    W <- changed to W for see not match D because not P, S
9    D    C    S

#first condition, second condition
m1 = (df["col2"] == 'C') & (df["col3"] == "W")
m2 = (df["col2"] == 'P') & (df["col3"] == "S")

#check if at least one True in m2 per groups
m3 = df['col1'].isin(df.loc[m2, 'col1'])

#details
print (df.assign(m1 = m1, m2=m2, m3=m3, 
                 m1_m3 = (m1 & m3), num = (m1 & m3).view('i1')))
  col1 col2 col3     m1     m2     m3  m1_m3  num
0    A    P    S  False   True   True  False    0
1    A    C    W   True  False   True   True    1
2    A    C    W   True  False   True   True    1
3    A    C    M  False  False   True  False    0
4    B    P    S  False   True   True  False    0
5    B    C    M  False  False   True  False    0
6    B    C    M  False  False   True  False    0
7    D    P    W  False  False  False  False    0
8    D    C    W   True  False  False  False    0
9    D    C    S  False  False  False  False    0
```

---

```
#filter only groups if m1 and m3 with aggregate sum for count
df = (m1 & m3).view('i1').groupby(df['col1']).sum().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  col1  count
0    A      2
1    B      0
2    D      0
```

Comment: @Carmine - Not sure if understand question, do you need count only groups by `col1` if at least one True matched by `m2` ?

Comment: I need to count all the pairs `C \in col2 - W \in col3` inside the groups by `col1` for which the condition "When there is a `P \in col2 - S \in col3`" is satisfied.

Comment: @Carmine - I think then answer is what need

Answer (score 0):

```
df['is_CW']=[(x=='C' and y=='W') for x, y in zip(df.col2, df.col3)]
df['is_PS']=[(x=='P' and y=='S') for x, y in zip(df.col2, df.col3)]
pv=df.pivot_table(values=['is_CW','is_PS'], index = 'col1', aggfunc=['sum'])
pv.columns=['is_CW','is_PS']
pv['answer'] = pv['is_CW'] * np.sign(pv['is_PS'])
print (pv.index, pv.answer)

A    2.0
B    0.0
D    0.0
```